# Adding autocomplete for text-field

Tags: 8, forms

I tried to implement an autocomplete in text-field for drupal 8 in my custom module

all I wanted was to fetch and display the likely title I typed via autocomplete
so declared a public function autocomplete within a class  in DefaultController.php 
in folder directory -->mymodule/src/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class DefaultController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function autocomplete($string)
    {
        $matches = array();
        $db = \Drupal::database();
        $result = $db->select('node_field_data', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('title', 'nid'))
        ->condition('title', '%'.db_like($string).'%', 'LIKE')
        ->addTag('node_access')
        ->execute();

        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $matches[$row->nid] = check_plain($row->title);
        }

        return new JsonResponse($matches);
    }
}
```

then created an EditForm.php in 
folder directory -->mymodule/src/Form/EditForm.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class EditForm extends FormBase
{
    public function getFormId()
    {
        return 'mymodule_edit_form';
    }

    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $form = array();

  $form['input_fields']['nid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name of the referenced node'),
    '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'mymodule.autocomplete',
    '#description' => t('Node Add/Edit type block'),
    '#default' => ($form_state->isValueEmpty('nid')) ? null : ($form_state->getValue('nid')),
    '#required' => true,
  );

        $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Create'),
  );

        return $form;
    }
}
```

also created mymodule.routing.yml

```
  mymodule.autocomplete:
  path: '/mymodule/autocomplete'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\DefaultController::autocomplete'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

still autocomplete functionality not getting implemented ?
Can anybody point me what am i missing ??

Comment: you need to pass parameters also https://www.drupal.org/node/2070985

Comment: @ShreyaShetty  No I don't need  parameters since 
in d7 i would have used 
'#autocomplete_path' => 'mymodule/autocomplete',
so in d8 i used
'#autocomplete_route_name' => 'mymodule.autocomplete',
so i never used parameter nor do i need one ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your class need some modification you need to check request and put it into $string.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode;

class DefaultController extends ControllerBase
{

  /**
   * Returns response for the autocompletion.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
   *   The current request object containing the search string.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
   *   A JSON response containing the autocomplete suggestions.
   */

  public function autocomplete(request $request) {
    $matches = array();
    $string = $request->query->get('q');
    if ($string) {
      $matches = array();
      $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->condition('title', '%'.db_like($string).'%', 'LIKE');
      //->condition('field_tags.entity.name', 'node_access');
      $nids = $query->execute();
      $result = entity_load_multiple('node', $nids);
      foreach ($result as $row) {
        //$matches[$row->nid->value] = $row->title->value;
        $matches[] = ['value' => $row->nid->value, 'label' => $row->title->value];
      }
    }
    return new JsonResponse($matches);
  }
}
```

Comment: it still DID NOT WORK after fetching a request and placing it into $string

Comment: have you check your request was print?

Comment: I think `\Drupal::entityQuery('node')` would be preferable to use apart of select.

Comment: After watching the Network tab in my browser's dev tools, I could see proper results in the response, but they were not being shown in the UI. After some digging, I found I had some custom css setting a `z-index` on a DOM element which contained the form. The value was too high and was overlapping the autocomplete results. Lowering my custom `z-index` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to select an entity, then there is a way easier way to do that. Drupal 8 has a standard entity_autocomplete field type, just specify your form element like this:

```
$form['node'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'node',
];
```

See [Custom autocomplete field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198637/custom-autocomplete-field) for more information.

Also, never do database queries against node/entity tables. Use \Drupal::entityQuery() for that.

Comment: Hi Berdir, How to get data from taxanomy in my case "city" using above code as it is working perfectly fine for node but not for taxanomy??

Comment: Thanks @Berdir, excellent answer. For term selection:       $form['related'] = [
        '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
        '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
        '#selection_settings' => [
          'target_bundles' => ['topics'],
        ],
      ];

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a routing.yml file and add the below code :
   admin_example.autocomplete:

:

```
  path: '/admin_example/autocomplete'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\admin_example\Controller\AdminNotesController::autocomplete'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

2. The form which you have build in mymodule/src/Form/EditForm.php is correct

You need to change the code in controller .The code is below :

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{
 $string = $request->query->get('q');
    $matches = array();
      $query = db_select('node_field_data', 'n')
          ->fields('n', array('title', 'nid'))
          ->condition('title', $string . '%', 'LIKE')
          ->execute()
          ->fetchAll();
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $matches[] = array('value' => $row->nid, 'label' => $row->title);
    }

    return new JsonResponse($matches);
}
```

Comment: Hi Shreya, I used your solution but instead of going to the form it is giving me o/p like this: [{"value":"1","label":"Patel Residency"},{"value":"2","label":"Jain Plaza"},{"value":"3","label":"Kanha Resort"},{"value":"38","label":"Hira Residency"}]. I want it to goto the form and the field should work as autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

Use @vgoradiya code then on the foreach loop try it this way:

```
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $matches[] = ['value' => $row->nid, 'label' => check_plain($row->title)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I had the same need and was greatly helped by the excellent write-up over at https://antistatique.net/en/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-autocomplete-entity-field-widget-using-the-drupal-8-form-api