# When using "Filter by an entity reference view," can I enable the "Create referenced entities if they don't already exist" option?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have an entity reference field for taxonomy terms on a node.

The *Default* **Reference method** has the option *Create referenced entities if they don't already exist*.

This lets me add new terms via the entity reference field when creating a node.

I want to restrict the terms that can be selected, so I set the **Reference method** to *Views: Filter by an entity reference view*.

However, when filtering by an entity reference view, I can't add new terms via the entity reference field when creating a node.

Is there a way to use *Views: Filter by an entity reference view* and still let users create new terms?

Additional info: My custom views filter simply filters the terms to those that were created by the logged-in user, so in this case, there is no possibility that allowing users to create terms would make it impossible for them to use the created terms on the node.

Comment: Workaround, you could either programmatically via hook_form_alter use [custom autocomplete](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200038/adding-autocomplete-for-text-field) OR via hook_form_alter add custom validation that creates the term if it doesn't already exist.